# WPF page not showing content

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a WPF application, where i have build a redirect if certain conditions are not met. It seems to redirect correctly, but it does not show the contents of the Xaml file..

It redirects from my GamePage to a GameSettingsPage.

The main window works as a master view, and the pages, i place inside a frame (_mainframe) which is inside a stackpanel, so i can switch out the contents without actually going completely away from the mainwindow.

Hope it makes sense, because after several hours, i have yet to find the issue why it will not show the game settings page...

**my code:**

*Main Window*

```
public partial class MainWindow : INavigator
{


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ExitGame(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    public void Navigate(Page p)
    {
        _mainFrame.Navigate(p);
    }

    private void NavigateRulesWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Navigate(new GameRulesPage());
    }

    private void NavigateGameWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Navigate(new GamePage(this));
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

*Game Page*

```
public partial class GamePage : Page
{
    private int numberOfPlayers;
    private Player[] players;
    private int playerTurn = 0;
    private int diceThrow;
    private GameState state;
    private int delay = 500;
    private Dice dice = new Dice();
    private GameProperties _writeHelper;
    private GameRules _gameRules;

    private INavigator _navigator;

    public GamePage(INavigator navigator)
    {
        _navigator = navigator; //assign navigator so i can navigate _mainframe to other pages.

        // initialize game properties, check if they are set.
        var gameProp = new GameProperties();
        this.numberOfPlayers = 2;

        this.players = gameProp.CheckPlayerIsSet(this.players);
        //check if a player has been set
        if (this.players != null)
        { // Player is set or has been set. proceed or start the game.
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        else
        {   // redirect to settings window because players has not been set!
            _navigator.Navigate(new GameSettingsPage(_navigator));
        }
    }
}
```

*Game Settings Page*

```
public partial class GameSettingsPage : Page
{
    private INavigator _navigator;

    public GameSettingsPage(INavigator navigator)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _navigator = navigator; //assign navigator so i can navigate _mainframe to other pages.
    }
}
```

*For good measure, my interface*

```
public interface INavigator
{
    void Navigate(Page p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the order of execution, try placing a breakpoint into the *Navigate(Page)* method and you'll see what's happening.

To explain why nothing is displayed, let's look at what happens.

1. You call the *NavigateGameWindow()* method.
2. It starts constructing *GamePage* object.
3. The condition goes into the else section.
4. *GameSettingsPage* is constructed.
5. *_mainFrame.Navigate* is called and *_mainFrame* navigates to the *GameSettingsPage*.
6. Thread continues executing so nothing will be displayed yet.
7. *MainWindow.Navigate()* returns back to the *GamePage constructor*, which is finished.
8. Execution is now back in the *NavigateGameWindow*, which calls *MainWindow.Navigate()* again with the object of *GamePage* type.
9. *_mainFrame* navigates to the *GamePage* object.

The reason nothing is displayed (and not the *GamePage*) is that you don't call the *InitializeComponents()* in it's constructor when the condition isn't met.

Comment: I am not trying to display GamePage, i am trying to, if a player is not set, so gamepage can access that player, i want to go to settings page, to set the player. Which means redirecting from gamepage, to settingspage, and displaying the view for settingspage.

Comment: I understand that. The reason GameSettingsPage is not displayed is that in step 9 the __mainFrame_ navigates to the (not initialized) GamePage object. That overrides the Navigate from step 5. As I said, your best place to start is to put a breakpoint in the Navigate method and you'll clearly see what's happening.